# Connecting a dozen raspberry pi to a router without changing static IP adress

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ethernet

I'm working on a system where a server and a dozen raspberry pi are connected to a router with wifi to communicate with each other.

Problem : the wifi is too slow so I have to use ethernet. I thought about using some hub/switch because my router only have 4 RJ45 port, but each of my raspberry pi have a static ip adress and I need to keep it that way. The server will be connected to the router directly, and ideally the raspberry will be connected to the router with 3 different hub or switch by group of 4.

So my question is : what kind of material does I need to make this system works with ethernet ? I think I need a switch but I don't know if it will span a new local network or keeps the old one and the static ip adress ?

As you probably noticed, networking is not my strong point so thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser! Glad to see you participating. What have you looked into so far? Any websearches perhaps? Did you find anything that looked useful but you did not (fully) understand? If so, please include that in your question, it helps others to come up with a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what kind of material do I need to make this system works with ethernet ?

A switch will do. Any switch, managed or unmanaged, Fast Ethernet or Gigabit (depending on the RPi models and your speed requirements). Just make sure that it's got enough ports.

If you're looking for plug & play, get a simple, unmanaged switch. Managed switches need to be configured (admin password, spanning tree, VLANs).

> I think I need a switch but I don't know if it will span a new local network or keeps the old one and the static ip adress ?

A (simple) switch just extends the port count for your existing network, nothing more.

You'll have to move static DHCP reservations over to the Ethernet MAC addresses of the RPis though, they likely point to their Wi-Fi MACs currently. If addresses are configured locally on the RPIs, that needs change as well as the NIC changes.

Additionally, I'm assuming the router bridges Wi-Fi and Ethernet to a shared segment & subnet (thx Tonny!). If it doesn't there's no simple way to keep the Wi-Fi IP addresses on Ethernet.

Comment: With one minor caveat... (and you might want to edit that into your answer....) As long as the router provides the SAME ip subnet on the wired and the WIFi network. The vast majorioty will do that, but not all.

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, I w'ill try first with an unmanaged switch.
Right now the router handle the static ip adress with a MAC adresses <--> ip adress configuration, and I think the MAC adresses used are the adresses of the RPi directly.

Comment: Just take note that Wi-Fi and Ethernet use different NICs with different MAC address (the MAC is NIC-specific, not host-specific).